# How to move a HTML list below a div

Tags: html

[At this URL](http://test.doig.com.au/meyer/), I'd like to move the HTML list form below the image.

I have `<div class="calculators" style="width: 50%; float: left;">` and a HTML form below this, but the form ends up on the right of the `<div>`.

How do I add it below the `<div>`?

Thanks.

Comment: Because the div is floated left. So anything added after it, is going to appear to the right of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a

```
<br class="cleanBreak">
```

at the end of your div. So that it's like this:

```
<div class="calculators" style="width: 50%; float: left;"><br class="cleanBreak">
```

and add this to your CSS:

```
.cleanBreak{ clear:both; }
```

Or if you want to do inline CSS like you did with your div, just do

```
<br style="clear:both;">
```

And that should fix it. If it doesn't I suggest showing some more code.

This is like pressing "enter" on your keyboard, it skips a  line and is nice to use to make things less jumbled.

Comment: Adding a <br> to the end did not fix it unfortunately.

Comment: Check out my above edit and see if the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

The calculators div seems to be `float: right`. `float: left` will fix that.

Comment: I've changed it to `<div style="width: 50%; float: right;" class="calculators"><strong>Calculators</strong></div>` and the issue remains.